# OpenCV - RGB Channels in Float Data Type and Intensity Range within 0-255

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

How can I achieve the values of the RGB channels as

- Float data type
- Intensity range within 0-255

I used CV_32FC4 as the matrix type since I'll perform floating-point mathematical operations to implement Daltonization. I was expecting that the intensity range is the same with the intensity range of the RGB Channels in CV_8UC3, just having a different data type. But when I printed the matrix I noticed that the intensities of the channels are not within 0-255. I realized that it due to the range of the float [matrix type](http://ninghang.blogspot.com/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html).

```
Mat mFrame(height, width, CV_32FC4, (unsigned char *)pNV21FrameData);

for(int y = 0 ; y < height ; y++){
    for(int x = 0 ; x < width ; x++){
        Vec4f BGRA = mFrame.at<Vec4f>(y,x);
        // Algorithm Implementation

        mFrame.at<Vec4f>(y,x) = BGRA;
    }
}

Mat mResult;
mFrame.convertTo(mResult, CV_8UC4, 1.0/255.0);
```

I need to manipulate the pixels like `BGRA[0] = BGRA[0] * n;` then assign it back to the matrix.

Comment: what's the range in the float matrix `mFrame`?

Comment: When I printed the float matrix I got values like  2.3693558e-38

Comment: Where does your `pNV21FrameData` comes from, is it already in float? or something else? You can have data in float matrix from 0-255.... and then you do not need to do the 1.0/255.0. This is only needed if it is in a range from 0-1

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ikkiChung/MyRealTimeImageProcessing/blob/master/JNI/ImageProcessing.cpp) is the original code.

Comment: I'm not sure about using CV_8UC4 as matrix type then conversion of data type (char to float), manipulate the pixels then convert it back.

Comment: I am writing a complete answer, just give me a minute :) but more or less that is the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your comments and the link in it I see that the data comes in BGRA. The data is in uchar.

I assume this from this line:

```
Mat mResult(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)poutPixels);
```

To solve this you can create the matrix and then convert it to float.

```
Mat mFrame(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)pNV21FrameData);
Mat mFloatFrame;
mFrame.convertTo(mFloatFrame, CV_32FC4);
```

Notice that this will keep the current ranges (0-255) if you need another one (like 0-1) you may put the scaling factor.

Finally you can convert back, but beware that this function does [`saturate_cast`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#saturate-cast). If you have an specific way you want to manage the overflow or the decimals, you will have to do it before converting it.

```
Mat mResult;
mFloatFrame.convertTo(mResult, CV_8UC4);
```

Note that `1.0/255.0` is not there, since the data is already in the range of 0-255 (at least before the operations).

One final comment, the link in your comments use IplImage and other old C (deprecated) versions of OpenCv. If you are working in c++, stick to the c++ versions like Mat. This is not in the code you show here, but in the you linked. This comment is more for you to avoid future headaches.

Comment: When I convert it back how does saturate_cast works? Will the value be estimated to a whole number?

Comment: quoting the documentation: " When the parameter is a floating-point value and the target type is an integer (8-, 16- or 32-bit), the floating-point value is first rounded to the nearest integer and then clipped if needed (when the target type is 8- or 16-bit)." so it will be rounded and clipped if needed (e.g. -1.3123 = 0,   256.54 = 255, 125.9 = 126,  18.0 = 18)

Comment: Upvote & Marked as answer aren't enough to express my gratitude to people who entertain my questions. Although this must be flagged, Thank you!

Comment: @Moon don't worry :) I am glad to be of help, and if you have more questions just ask, that is the purpose of Stack Overflow is.